# Camera target point based on angles

Tags: c++, mathematics

I'm working on a test project to learn some basic OpenGL. Right now I'm trying to work on a "camera" with gluLookAt. My camera object is really simple, I have two vectors, one for the position and the other for the rotation (x, y and z on both). I'm having trouble with the target point gluLookAt receives, how can I find a target point using only the position and camera angle?

Comment: What do you mean by finding a target point? Are your inputs: camPos, camOrientation(x,y,z) and targetPos(x,y,z)? You don't need a camera angle if you have its camOrientation vector.. Sorry, it's a tad ambiguous

Comment: I think I meant Orientation instead of Rotation. I don't have the target, only the camera position angles on each axis, I'm trying to find a target with that.

Comment: You have the position/eye for the glulookat. If you assume the camera looking towards _(0,0,-1)_ and the up vector to be _(0,1,0)_ as usually with OpenGL, then you must construct a matrix _M_ from your angles (use Euler angles.. but beware of the infamous gimbal lock issue). Once you get the _M_, your direction is _M * (0,0,-1)_, your up vector _M*(0,1,0)_. To find the center/lookatpoint, add to your _camPos_ the _M*(0,0,-1)_ vector. There you go. This is a bad way to do it, but it's educational.. go for angle-axis and quaternions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have desired rotation angles for your camera, then `gluLookAt` is not really the appropriate function to use.  Instead, use `glRotate` three times, once for each axis of rotation (typically in roll, pitch, yaw order) using the negative of the desired camera angle on each axis, then `glTranslate` with the negative of the camera position.

(Why the negatives?  Because you're constructing a matrix to go from world space to camera space, so everything's opposite to the transformations that go from camera space to world space.)

Answer (score 0):

The position passed to `gluLookAt()` is relative to the origin.  Since you have one point relative to another point, then get that point relative to the origin by subtracting the second point from it, i.e.

```
V1 - V2 = (v1.x-v2.x,v1.y-v2.y,v1.z-v2.z)
```

And pass the result to `gluLookAt()`.

After calling `gluLookat()`, call `glTranslate()` to "move" the camera to its position vector.