# Given a constant rotation and target point, find position so that point will be in camera center

Tags: c#, unity, mathematics, camera, input

Given a fixed rotation and a target "center" point, how to I find the position the camera should be in so that that point is the center? [LookAt](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) changes the rotation keeping the position constant. Basically, I'm trying to do the reverse, but the math escapes me :-). Thanks!

Camera is currently psuedo-isometric (orthographic with rotation from Euler angles [X:35.264389683ish°, Y:45°, Z:0°]). Might want to change these a bit or allow rotation though, so ideally a solution would work for any rotation. Can easily get the projection matrix.

EDIT: thinking about it, there would be infinite such positions that satisfy this constraint. I would want to fix the Y component of the position (camera height) and find only an X/Z.

Thanks to Mokosha's answer below, here's the final code I'm using:

```
    private static Vector3 reverseLookAt(Quaternion cameraRotation, float cameraHeight, Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        Vector3 d = cameraRotation * Vector3.forward;
        Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, -cameraHeight);
        Ray ray = new Ray(targetPosition, d);
        Vector3 pos = UnityUtils.intersect(ray, plane);
        return pos;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rephrase your question:

Given a rotation `R`, and a position `p`, we would like the rotated point `p'` to lie along the Z-axis (also known as the center of the camera). For this, we can use linear algebra:

1. [Compose the rotation matrix](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=846) `R` from your euler angles.
2. Solve problem (1) which we can rewrite as (2):
   $$\begin{align}Rd&=\begin{vmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix}^T \tag 1\\
    \\
   d &= R^{-1}\begin{vmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   1
   \end{vmatrix}\tag 2\end{align}$$
3. `d` is now the direction in world space that corresponds to the Z-axis of the camera in eye space. Construct `p'` by translating `p` by `d`: `p' = p + d`.
4. Using `p` and `p'`, construct a line `P`.
5. [Compute the intersection](http://geomalgorithms.com/a05-_intersect-1.html) of `P` with the plane whose normal is `[0 1 0]` at `D` distance away from the origin where `D` is the desired Y value of your camera in world units.

The code for this in Unity's C# would look something like this:

```
Quaternion rot = ...
Vector3 p = ...
float desired_y = ...

Vector3 d = rot * (new Vector3(0, 0, 1)); // Perhaps Camera.forward...?

Vector3 camPos;
if (Mathf.Abs(d.y) < Mathf.epsilon) {
  Log.Error("Camera direction parallel to XZ plane");
} else {
  Plane y_plane = new Plane(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), desired_y);
  float dist;
  y_plane.Raycast(new Ray(p, p + d), dist)
  camPos = r.GetPoint(dist);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Step 2 seems like it's missing something though since p' = inv(R)*(0,0,1) doesn't seem to involve p at all.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong terminology, `d` is the *direction* in world space that you need to translate `p`. I've edited my post.

Comment: Tried that and something still seems off. For example using the above rotation, targetPos = (0, 0, 0) and desired_y = 10 (and flipping direction), I get a point at (-17.32051, 10, 14.14213), which seems way off in no man's land. The solution looks to be somewhere around (-10, 10, -6) or so.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out! You don't invert the rotation.

Comment: It depends on how your [rotation is defined](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27802/camera-target-point-based-on-angles?rq=1). I've updated the code for Unity's conventions.